# How to color a BSplineSurface

Tags: graphics3d, color, splines

I am trying to color a `BSplineSurface` in a complex way but not having any luck using `ColorFunction`. I can use `ColorFunction` if I using `BSplineFunction` and `ParametricPlot3D` but would prefer not to go that route. Here is an example of the surface I would like to color:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], SeedRandom[4];
  BSplineSurface[Table[{x, y, 0.25 + UnitStep[30 - Abs[x] - 0.001] UnitStep[50 -Abs[y] - 0.001] (0.25/RandomReal[{0.1, 2}]^2)}, 
  {x, -30, 30, 5.}, {y, -50, 50, 5.}]]}, Boxed -> False]
```

I would like to be able to color the peaks with one color (red) and have that color fade away to gray in the flat parts.[image]

Comment: I *think* that you cannot, as it's a single graphics object.  But you *can* construct a `BSplineFunction`, use `Plot3D` to plot it, and use `ColorFunction` in `Plot3D`.  This'll build up the plot from many graphics objects (polygons), each of which will be separately coloured based on your `ColorFunction`

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[4];
pts = Table[{x, y, 0.25 + UnitStep[30 - Abs[x] - 0.001] UnitStep[50 - Abs[y] - 0.001]
            (0.25/RandomReal[{0.1, 2}]^2)}, {x, -30,  30, 5}, {y, -50, 50, 5}];

ParametricPlot3D[
 BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> 2][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Blend[{Gray, Red}, z]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]  [image]